# How do I configure SQL Server Express 2017 for IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-10

I have a new install of SQL Server Express 2017 running on Windows Server 2016. IIS 10 cannot access the database on this SQL Server. (No problem from Visual Studio.) What security do I need to configure in SQL Server, IIS, and the file system (.mdf files)? I have researched this for many hours, but cannot find a current solution. I used to be able to solve this by adding NETWORK SERVICE or SYSTEM under NT AUTHORITY, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Does something have to be done with Application Pools?

Comment: The error I get is "Cannot open database xxx requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user "WEBBER\s4$" where WEBBER is the domain and S4 is the machine name.

Comment: This means that or this database is not online, or you did not map your login to this database

Comment: I believe I did "not map your login". My question is what account do I block, i.e., what account is IIS running under??

Comment: The Services app says the service is running as "local system", but I can't seem to give privileges to that name.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I guess that you should map your login to your database:

```
use xxx;
create user [WEBBER\s4$] from login [WEBBER\s4$];
```

This will fix your error but for normal working you should also give the necessary permissions to your user.

If it should have control over database xxx, make him db_owner like this:

```
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER  [WEBBER\s4$];
```

The "strange" name you see is your pc's name, this is because Network Service or Local System accounts goes to network under the pc name.

Comment: Thanks sepupic. I did both of these (successfully), bur the problem remains.It still says the login fails.

Comment: Are you sure you did "use xxx" first?

Comment: Does the error still cite WEBBER\s4$ or maybe it's NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM? If all this happens locally, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM should be NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and not WEBBER\s4$. Try to do the same with [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM] login: map it to database xxx and make him db_owner

Comment: I executed the following script:

use cagcgolfaspnetdb
create user [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM] from login [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM];
go

ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM]
go

for both cagcgolf and cagcgolfaspnetdb

Comment: Is it "cagcgolfaspnetdb" or "cagcgolf" that you see in the error message? You need to map the problem login to the problem database, so the login and database name should be the same that you see in the error message

Comment: But do you confirm that you mapped it to the correct database?

Comment: It is CAGCGolfaspnetdb. I have made both have SYSTEM and NETWORK SERVICE as users.

Comment: Do I need to change the IIS login somehow?

Comment: They want me to move the discussion to chat, but I do not have enough experience on stackoverflow.com to allow this.

Comment: If you did "use CAGCGolfaspnetdb; create user [WEBBER\s4$] from login [WEBBER\s4$];" it should resolve your problem. Both Network Service and Local System are mapped to pcName$ when out of this pc

Comment: Can it be that you have more then one server and you mapped the login on one server but the error is on the other?

Comment: I did it again (successfully according to SSMS). Same problem. This works fine undex Visual Studio, so it has something to do with the way IIS runs, no?

Comment: I have only the one server.

Comment: Please execute from SSMS: use master; execute as login = 'WEBBER\s4$'; use CAGCGolfaspnetdb; select user; select * from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'database');

Comment: What user does it return and how many rowsdo you get by executing the last query?

Comment: I did. It returned with 3 entity names:
CONNECT, VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY DEFINITION, and VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION.
It also said under (No column name) WEBBER\s4$

Comment: What user name was returned? The permissions returned are NOT db_owner's permissions, you should get at least 61 rows, so there is something wrong with what you did

Comment: It returned 1 row, then 3 rows.

Comment: When it return 1 row, what user it was?

Comment: You surely mapped smth else, because the permissions you showed are NOT db_owner's permissions

Comment: use master
execute as login = 'WEBBER\s4$';
use CAGCGolfaspnetdb;
select user;
select * from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'database');
go

then i just got:

Msg 15406, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "WEBBER\s4$" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

Comment: When you get this error, did you checked if LOGIN WEBBER\s4$ exists? Do you see it under security in object explorer?

Comment: You DID NOT map it because or you are not sysadmin or this login does not exist

Comment: I'm sorry I'm taking up too much of your time (but very grateful). I'll do more experimenting on my own. Thanks